# Direct3D Acceleration on Windows XP VirtualBox VM

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, emulator

I'm trying to run Project64 2.2 on a Windows XP Virtual Machine. Unfortunately, when I run it, I get the following error message

[image]

After doing some digging, it seems to be an issue with Direct3D Acceleration. Running dxdiag and checking it out, my settings look like this...

[image]

Apparently, installing the guest additions for the virtual machine is supposed to fix the problem, but it didn't for me. I even checked the Direct3d box in the installation process but nothing. I don't get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aside of installing the guest addons, you also need to enable Direct3D support for the Virtual Machine.

1. `Shutdown` the VM
2. `Click the VM` from Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
3. Press the `settings` button
4. Open the `Display` tab on the left
5. Check `enable 3D acceleration` next to Extra options.
6. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> to save your settings and start the VM.

Comment: This worked, but I have a limited resolution options inside game only 640x480, 800x600 and 1024x768 are available... how to get full screen in game?

Comment: @lewis4u Resolutions in-game will not change. If you can't get a higher resolution, then that simply mean that game is so old, it did not support higher resolutions.